# How to get xmin and xmax work for small interval?

Tags: pgfplotstable

The following uses a small sample of a huge data set which is bounded by x = 0 and x = 2. However, there is a need for plotting the results at the intervall [1.371508664312009 1.371508780212562]. This does however not work with the following code. What is wrong? (I obviously could scale the result, but I want a more general solution as this occurse quite often in my thesis)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt,png]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        cycle list={%
            {black}
        },
        xmin = 1.371508664312009,
        xmax = 1.371508780212562,
        ]
        \addplot[unbounded coords=discard] table[x=k,y=F_k] {
k                   F_k
1.371508647597729   4.218629299064943
1.371508655954869   4.367306455608867
1.371508664312009   4.546736697704027
1.371508672669148   4.767650229729832
1.371508710724181   7.117825185499241
1.371508713560441   7.513271582940213
1.371508716396702   7.985684237353307
1.371508719232962   8.552417433810986
1.371508722069223   9.245525102110591
1.371508724905483   10.115770661107760
1.371508727741744   11.225899722988125
1.371508730578004   12.667837277184283
1.371508737113507   17.998622084719759
1.371508738663157   19.703601372911169
1.371508739179707   20.274665134457187
1.371508739696257   20.825915113218606
1.371508742279008   22.855385665696630
1.371508742795558   22.988513291704997
1.371508745120034   21.959402178915621
1.371508745636584   21.414072973829519
1.371508746153134   20.769375301115637
1.371508746669684   20.063715232649155
1.371508763194999   5.048020735228436
1.371508766031260   4.141215569327951
};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think, this is a precision issue

Comment: Yes, but in the pgf plots manual it say that the full double range is supported in general. But clearly not in this case. Is it possible to increase the precision?

Comment: I think it's possible, but I am no `pgfplots` expert, sorry.

Comment: TeX isn't optimised for numeric calculation, but even if it was, the `k` values seem ureasonable to plot, can't you subtract `1.3715086` from all values, then rescale the function?

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But as I said, this causes a lot of more work for me as this occurs often (what I am doing here is a zoom up of an interesting area). But I do not know what you mean by it being unreasonable to plot, as it should intuitively be easy to plot with high precision. (double precision should do the trick)

Comment: Double precision is not used to transform TeX fixed-point to pgfplots fpu format while parsing axis options.

Comment: Well, of course double precision would allow you to do this, but I would personnally struggle with reading such numbers in a paper. If you need people to read this plot, I'm not sure it is reasonable to use this scale.

Comment: As percusse says fixed point arithmetic is used here but even if floating point were being used, by adding `1.37150876` on to each value you are using up half the precision just for holding the offset, transforming the axis would be the correct thing to do whatever the plotting software

Answer (score 1):

This will not work even if you use fpu format. See the warning after the conversion by `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{1.371508664312009}\xdef\myxmin{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{1.371508780212562}\xdef\myxmax{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
    \begin{axis}[,
        cycle list={%
            {black}
        },enlargelimits=false,
        xmin = \myxmin,
        xmax = \myxmax,
        ]
        \addplot[unbounded coords=discard] table[x=k,y=F_k] {
k                   F_k
1.371508647597729   4.218629299064943
1.371508655954869   4.367306455608867
1.371508664312009   4.546736697704027
1.371508672669148   4.767650229729832
1.371508710724181   7.117825185499241
1.371508713560441   7.513271582940213
1.371508716396702   7.985684237353307
1.371508719232962   8.552417433810986
1.371508722069223   9.245525102110591
1.371508724905483   10.115770661107760
1.371508727741744   11.225899722988125
1.371508730578004   12.667837277184283
1.371508737113507   17.998622084719759
1.371508738663157   19.703601372911169
1.371508739179707   20.274665134457187
1.371508739696257   20.825915113218606
1.371508742279008   22.855385665696630
1.371508742795558   22.988513291704997
1.371508745120034   21.959402178915621
1.371508745636584   21.414072973829519
1.371508746153134   20.769375301115637
1.371508746669684   20.063715232649155
1.371508763194999   5.048020735228436
1.371508766031260   4.141215569327951
};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

and the log file has the warning:

> Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis x is approximately empty; enlarging it (it is [1.3715086000000000:1.371508
>   8000000000]) on input line 46.
>
> [warning /pgfplots/warning/approx empty range enlarged]

If you really need this precision take away the constant part then take the log of your data and plot that. This actually won't work properly in any language without dedicated small int, big int libraries.